# How can I stop the IRS from withholding refunds for a student loan that is already paid off?

Tags: united-states, loans, irs, student-loan

I paid off my student loan over 10 years ago. The IRS is now withholding my refunds. How can I prove this loan has been paid?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what happened - i.e., what form of notice you received, were you served papers of a judgement against you prior to this, etc? In general the legal process that enabled the request to the IRS to withhold the refund is the process you must deal with directly, but its hard to advise without knowing any more about what that process might have been and what you know about it.

Comment: You prove your loan is paid with a letter from the lender saying it's paid. Can you confirm the accounts are closed and/or the balances are $0? Is there a loan you didnt know about that's been brewing? That seems to be a common issue among students with multiple loans, too.

Comment: What does the IRS have to do with a student loan? They collect federal taxes.

Comment: @chepner the IRS can seize tax refunds to pay off federally guaranteed student loans that are in default.

Comment: It's not _IRS_, which only offsets for federal tax (and penalties/interest); instead _Treasury_, more exactly [BFS the Bureau of the Fiscal Service](https://fiscal.treasury.gov/top/) formerly FMS the Financial Management Service, offsets for other federal debts (like student loans) and certain state claims (including child support and state tax). BFS/TOP can't correct your records itself, but should be able to [get you in contact with the agency](https://fiscal.treasury.gov/dms/contact.html) who can.